# WebStorm Angular template error with same type: Type A is not assignable to type A

Tags: angular, webstorm

Given template:

```
<div [ngStyle]="style">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

And .ts:

```
  @Input() style: { [klass: string]: any } | null | undefined;
```

WebStorm is giving me:

[image]

I've tried restarting WebStorm and even tried downloading the latest EAP (2024.1) build but the error persists. Am I missing something obvious here?

Interestingly it seems like `null` and `undefined` are the issue. If I make it just `@Input() style!: { [p: string]: any };` it stops complaining. But adding back either `null` or `undefined` makes it complain, even if they're defined alone:

[image]